# How can i make a browser view for many images to load them without stalling?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I want to scroll fluently through the images just like in photo album (camera roll). I'm using proxy pattern, but it is still not scrolling fluently. How is it made for the cameral roll? Or do they pre-load the images when powering on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

They load them in a background queue so it does not block the main UI.

Comment: Do they load them in background while scrolling through the images? And what do they use: an UITableView or an UIScrollView?

Comment: It's definitely not a UITableView. I think they've done it with UIScrollView or they could have done it with what they call UICollectionView which was internally available before making it public. Check out WWDC2012 sessions for more information about that.